# What are the advantages of long read sequencing for cancer oncogenomic research?

Tags: human-biology, dna, bioinformatics, homework, dna-sequencing

Currently I am using whole genome nanopore sequencing, Illumina short read and 10x linked read to study oncogenesis mechanisms of certain types of rare cancer. I am wondering about the advantages of nanopore sequencing in this field, e.g. fusion gene discovery, detection of large structural variants and copy number alterations (SV/CNA), as compared to Illumina and 10x?
I am struggling with generating my doctoral thesis proposal, so any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/s10038-019-0658-5

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, please summarize what you already know (with references to reliable sources) — this will make it clearer what information you need and also demonstrate that you have done the expected prior research. In addition, please write out abbreviations that are unlikely to be generally familiar. Thanks! 